# Convexity and positive semidefinitness .

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

There is a question that just popped up in my mind:

Let $P$ be a polyhedron and $f: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R $ be a quadratic function, i.e., $f$ admits the representation  $$f(x) = x^t Q x + b^t x + \alpha $$ where $Q$ is a $n \times n$ matrix. Assume $f$ is convex on $P$. Then can we find a positive semidefinite matrix $A$ and vector $a$ and scalar $\beta$  such that $$f(x) = x^t A x + a^t x + \beta  \quad \quad \forall x \in P$$

a) I guess no, looking for an example?  What if  $\mbox{int} \, P \ne \emptyset$?

Comment: This is definitely true, even if $P$ has an empty interior. But I'm commenting instead of answering because the proof might take longer than I have ;-)

Comment: This is a great news !  Could you please write at least an sketch of the proof or something  anytime you have time. I would be much appreciate @MichaelGrant

Comment: Could you clarify a bit what do you mean by "positive semidefinite matrix $A$"? Because if $P$ has an empty interior then it is possible that the function is convex on $P$, but $Q$ is not positive definite on the whole space, only on a subspace. For example, take $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $P=\{(x,y)\colon y=0\}$. The matrix is positive (semi)definite on $P$, but not on ${\mathbb R}^2$. What size of $A$ do you assume?

Comment: Positive definite on the whole space, and your example is not a counter example ! @A.Γ.

Comment: @Redshoes So what will be the matrix $A$ in my example?

Comment: A $4 \times 4$ matrix in which $a_{1,1} =1$ and  zero otherwise. @A.Γ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $P$ is a set with a non-empty [relative interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_interior), i.e. $\exists x_0\in\text{ri}\,P$.

1. Make a translation $P_0=\{\xi\colon \xi=x-x_0,\,x\in P\}$ and
   $$
   f(x)=f(x_0+\xi)=\phi(\xi).
   $$
   We have that $0\in\text{ri}\,P_0$ and
   $$
   f(x)=x^TQx+\langle\ldots\rangle\ \text{ is convex on }P \iff \phi(\xi)=\xi^TQ\xi+\langle\ldots\rangle \text{ is convex on }P_0.
   $$
   Here $\langle\ldots\rangle$ denotes linear and constant terms which do not affect convexity.
2. Let ${\cal M}$ denote the linear span of $P_0$ and ${\mathbb P}_{\cal M}$ the orthogonal projection on ${\cal M}$. Since $\phi$ is convex on $P_0$ that has non-empty interior in ${\cal M}$ we have
   $$
   \xi^TQ\xi\ge 0,\quad\forall\xi\in{\cal M}\ \iff \ {\mathbb P}_{\cal M}Q{\mathbb P}_{\cal M}\text{ pos.semidef}.
   $$
3. Now define $A={\mathbb P}_{\cal M}Q{\mathbb P}_{\cal M}$ and
   $$
   \psi(\xi)=\phi({\mathbb P}_{\cal M}\xi)=\xi^TA\xi+\langle\ldots\rangle.
   $$
   Translating back
   $$
   q(x)=\psi(x-x_0)=x^TAx+\langle\ldots\rangle
   $$
   to get for $x\in P$
   $$
   f(x)=\phi(\xi)=\phi({\mathbb P}_{\cal M}\xi)=q(x)
   $$
   and $q$ is convex in ${\mathbb R}^n$.

Comment: Thanks I had similar idea to solve that, and I did.  that's why I asked this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2810818/219176

Answer (score 2):

If $P$ has an **interior point** $x$, then
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\bigg|_{t=0} \ f(x+tv) =(v,Qv)$$ for all $|v|=1$.
Since $f$ is convex, then $Q$ is a positive semidefinite matrix.
That is, $f$ is a convex function on $\mathbb{R}^n$.