# Is $Q + A$ postive semidefinte?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Q$ be a Matrix and $V \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be a vector subspace on which  $Q$ is positive semidefinite i.e,  $$\langle x  ,  Q x \rangle \ge 0 ~~~~~  \quad \forall x \in V $$

Prove or provide a counter example

There exist a matrix $A$ such that $Q + A$ is positive semidefinite (on whole $\Bbb R^n$) and

$$\langle x  ,  Q x \rangle  = \langle x  ,  (Q + A) x \rangle   \quad \quad x \in V.$$

Comment: if the last condition holds for all $v$ then $A$ is skew symmetric.

Comment: @WillJagy Are you sure that's true?  Suppose that $Q$ is a block matrix consisting of $I$ and $-I$.  Then, $A$ could be a block matrix consisting of $0$ and $I$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr   it was written so that $\langle x, Ax \rangle = 0$ for every vector $x,$ as the inner product is bilinear. The values of $\langle x, Qx \rangle $ just cancel out.

Comment: @WillJagy That equality is only for $x\in V$, not in all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr excellent point. It might be sensible for me to begin reading the entire questions, but, well, why change now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P$ is a projection onto $V$, then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
$$\langle x, P^T QPx \rangle = \langle Px, QPx \rangle \ge 0$$
since $Px \in V$, so $P^T QP$ is positive semidefinite. Moreover if $x \in V$ then $Px = x$, so
$$\langle x, P^T QPx \rangle = \langle Px, QPx \rangle = \langle x, Qx \rangle.$$
So pick $A = P^T QP - Q$ and we're done.

Comment: I think if you had $Q$ positive *definite* on $V$ and wanted something positive definite everywhere, you could just add something extra like $(I-P)^T (I-P)$. (I'm thinking of $I-P$ as a projection onto a subspace complementary to $V$.)

Comment: Thank you. Does same Trick work (Projection map onto $V$) For the case positive definite ?

Comment: @Redshoes As written, my solution will only give you a positive *semidefinite* matrix, but see my above comment.

Comment: my question is addressing your comment. What is A in PD case ?

Is this  $A = (I-P)^T  Q (I-P) - Q$ ?

Comment: No, what I mean is something like $A = P^T QP - Q + \epsilon (I-P)^T(I-P)$ for any $\epsilon>0$.