# Is $Q + A$ postive definte?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $Q$ be a Matrix and $V \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be a vector subspace on which  $Q$ is positive definite i.e,  $$\langle x  ,  Q x \rangle > 0 ~~~~~  \quad \forall x \in V \setminus \{0\} $$

Prove or provide a counter example

There exist a matrix $A$ such that $Q + A$ is positive definite (on whole $\Bbb R^n$) and

$$\langle x  ,  Q x \rangle  = \langle x  ,  (Q + A) x \rangle   \quad \quad x \in V.$$

Note that:
This question has been solved for the case Positive semidefinite. Here [Is $Q + A$ postive semidefinte?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2810818/219176)

Comment: Write $\mathbf{R}^n = V \oplus V^\perp$ and define $T = Q + A$ separately on $V$ and $V^\perp$.

Comment: How to define ? using projection ? @TrevorGunn